# Faster way of converting Date column to weekday name in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my input csv file that i read via pd.read_csv()

```
ProductCode,Date,Receipt,Total
x1,07/29/15,101790,17.35
x2,07/29/15,103601,8.89
x3,07/29/15,103601,8.58
x4,07/30/15,101425,11.95
x5,07/29/15,101422,1.09
x6,07/29/15,101422,0.99
x7,07/29/15,101422,3
y7,08/05/15,100358,7.29
x8,08/05/15,100358,2.6
z3,08/05/15,100358,2.99


import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('product.csv')

#I have to add some columns to the data:

df['Receipt_Count'] = df.groupby(['Date','Receipt'])['Receipt'].transform('count')
df['Day_of_Week'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.weekday_name
```

I have around 800K of lines in my csv file. When I run the line of code for the conversion of date to weekday_name, it takes me around 2 minutes. I know that Im converting my 'Date' column to datetime first because it is treated as a string from the csv then it gets converted to its weekday equivalent.  Is there any way I can shorten the conversion time?

I'm fairly new to Pandas/Python, so I'm not sure if i missed something here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Specifying the format of your date strings will speed up the conversion considerably:

```
df['Day_of_Week'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%m/%d/%y').dt.weekday_name
```

Here are some benchmarks:

```
import io
import pandas as pd

data = io.StringIO('''\
ProductCode,Date,Receipt,Total
x1,07/29/15,101790,17.35
x2,07/29/15,103601,8.89
x3,07/29/15,103601,8.58
x4,07/30/15,101425,11.95
x5,07/29/15,101422,1.09
x6,07/29/15,101422,0.99
x7,07/29/15,101422,3
y7,08/05/15,100358,7.29
x8,08/05/15,100358,2.6
z3,08/05/15,100358,2.99
''')

df = pd.read_csv(data)
%timeit pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.weekday_name
# => 100 loops, best of 3: 2.48 ms per loop
%timeit pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%m/%d/%y').dt.weekday_name
# => 1000 loops, best of 3: 507 µs per loop

large_df = pd.concat([df] * 1000)
%timeit pd.to_datetime(large_df['Date']).dt.weekday_name
# => 1 loop, best of 3: 1.62 s per loop
%timeit pd.to_datetime(large_df['Date'], format='%m/%d/%y').dt.weekday_name
# => 10 loops, best of 3: 45.9 ms per loop
```

Even for the small sample you provided in the OP, performance improves by a factor of 5 — for a larger dataframe it gets much, much better.

Comment: Specifying the format of the date string did the trick. From almost 2 mins processing down to 2seconds, thanks for that!  %timeit pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.weekday_name 1 loop, best of 3: 1min 50s per loop      %timeit pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%m/%d/%y').dt.weekday_name    1 loop, best of 3: 2.39 s per loop

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to load the csv with the date information, especially if you need this date column often. Unfortunately there does not seem to be a way to pass the format of the date in and the `infer_datetime_format` parameter to `read_csv` does not seem to make a difference:

```
import timeit

repeat = 3
numbers = 100

setup = """import pandas as pd
import io

data = io.StringIO('''\
ProductCode,Date,Receipt,Total
''' + '''\
x1,07/29/15,101790,17.35
x2,07/29/15,103601,8.89
x3,07/29/15,103601,8.58
x4,07/30/15,101425,11.95
x5,07/29/15,101422,1.09
x6,07/29/15,101422,0.99
x7,07/29/15,101422,3
y7,08/05/15,100358,7.29
x8,08/05/15,100358,2.6
z3,08/05/15,100358,2.99
''' * 100)"""


def time(statement, _setup=None):
    print (min(
        timeit.Timer(statement, setup=_setup or setup).repeat(
            repeat, numbers)))

time('pd.read_csv(data); data.seek(0)')
time('pd.read_csv(data, parse_dates=["Date"]); data.seek(0)')
time('pd.read_csv(data, parse_dates=["Date"],'
     'infer_datetime_format=True); data.seek(0)')
```

prints:

```
0.5536041843652657
25.298157679942697
25.34556727133409
```

But if you are to use the Date column often it should pay to convert it from the beginning.