# Extract date and time from pandas timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series

I have a `timestamp` column where the timestamp is in the following format

```
2016-06-16T21:35:17.098+01:00
```

I want to extract date and time from it. I have done the following:

```
import datetime as dt

df['timestamp'] = df['timestamp'].apply(lambda x : pd.to_datetime(str(x)))

df['dates'] = df['timestamp'].dt.date
```

This worked for a while. But suddenly it does not.

If I again do `df['dates'] = df['timestamp'].dt.date` I get the following error

```
Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values
```

Luckily, I have saved the data frame with `dates` in the csv but I now want to create another column `time` in the format `23:00:00.051`

**EDIT**

From the raw data file (15 million samples), the `timestamp` column looks like following (first 5 samples):

```
            timestamp

0           2016-06-13T00:00:00.051+01:00
1           2016-06-13T00:00:00.718+01:00
2           2016-06-13T00:00:00.985+01:00
3           2016-06-13T00:00:02.431+01:00
4           2016-06-13T00:00:02.737+01:00
```

After the following command

```
df['timestamp'] = df['timestamp'].apply(lambda x : pd.to_datetime(str(x)))
```

the `timestamp` column looks like with `dtype` as dtype: datetime64[ns]

```
0    2016-06-12 23:00:00.051
1    2016-06-12 23:00:00.718
2    2016-06-12 23:00:00.985
3    2016-06-12 23:00:02.431
4    2016-06-12 23:00:02.737
```

Then finally

```
df['dates'] = df['timestamp'].dt.date

0           2016-06-12
1           2016-06-12
2           2016-06-12
3           2016-06-12
4           2016-06-12
```

**EDIT 2**

Found the mistake. I had cleaned the data and saved the data frame in a csv file, so I don't have to do the cleaning again. When I read the csv, the timestamp `dtype` changes to object. Now how do I fix this?

Comment: well it means you have some duff values so you can force these duff values to `NaT`: `df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], errors='coerce')` then you can get rid of these values using `dropna` and then you can call `dt.date` as before

Comment: `df.timestamp.isnull().sum()` returns 0

Comment: Sorry but unless you post your raw data and code with errors then this becomes a hypothetical posturing exercise which wastes time

Comment: If checking with summing null values, you assume that incorrect values are null/interpreted as null. I'd doubt that

Comment: related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33365055/attributeerror-can-only-use-dt-accessor-with-datetimelike-values

Comment: I have posted the code to reproduce. I will try your method too now.

Comment: @chintans OT, instead of `df['timestamp'].apply(lambda x : pd.to_datetime(str(x)))`, consider `pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])`.

Comment: Is it because you have imported `datetime` as `dt` and then calling the `dt` accessor attribute resulting in it being overshadowed and thereby resulting in the error?

Comment: That seems to be the mistake. I think @Ami 's solution will work. It just takes a lot of time to apply it to 15 million samples :)

Comment: OK, found the mistake. I had cleaned the data and saved the data frame in a csv file, so I dont have to do the cleaning again. When I read the csv, the `timestamp` dtype changes to object. Now how do I fix this?

Comment: @chintans look at the `converters` argument for `pd.read_csv`...

Comment: @chintans To speed up the conversion, specify the format of your datetime strings --- see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39548139/faster-way-of-converting-date-column-to-weekday-name-in-pandas/39548416#39548416).

Answer (score 55):

Do this first:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
```

Before you do your extraction as usual:

```
df['dates'] = df['time'].dt.date
```

Answer (score 24):

If date is in string form then:

```py
import datetime

# this line converts the string object in Timestamp object
df['DateTime'] = [datetime.datetime.strptime(d, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M") for d in df["DateTime"]]

# extracting date from timestamp
df['Date'] = [datetime.datetime.date(d) for d in df['DateTime']] 

# extracting time from timestamp
df['Time'] = [datetime.datetime.time(d) for d in df['DateTime']]
```

If the object is already in the Timestamp format then skip the first line of code.

`%Y-%m-%d %H:%M` this means your timestamp object must be in the form like  `2016-05-16 12:35:00`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use pandas built-in `to_datetime` object for this

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
df['date'] = df['timestamp'].dt.date
df['time'] = df['timestamp'].dt.time
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are importing your csv, then use `parse_dates` parameter of `pandas.read_csv()`. For example, to import a column `utc_datetime` as datetime:

```
parse_dates = ['utc_datetime']
df = pandas.read_csv('file.csv', parse_dates=parse_dates)
```

To extract date from timestamp, use numpy instead of pandas:

```
df['utc_date'] = numpy.array(df['utc_datetime'].values, dtype='datetime64[D]')
```

Numpy datetime operations are significantly faster than pandas datetime operations.