# Selecting part of a string in Pandas Series

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a string as follows: `2020-01-01T16:30.00 - 1.00`. I want to select the string that is between `T` and  `-` , i.e. I want to be able to select `16:30.00` out of the whole string and convert it to a float. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should use `datetime` type for date/time data.

Comment: The data comes in the format I showed. How to I select the time part out of it.

Comment: df['your_column'].apply( lambda x: str(x)[-15:-7] ), if and only if the format stays the same

Comment: It doesn't stay the same, I am looking for something general.

Comment: I found the following answer that does it efficiently. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39662149/pandas-extract-date-and-time-from-timestamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a pandas Series `s` like this

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series(["2020-01-01T16:30.00 - 1.00", "2020-12-04T00:25.00 - 14.00"])
```

you can use

```
s.str.replace(".+T", "").str.replace(" -.+", "")
# 0    16:30.00
# 1    00:25.00
# dtype: object
```

Basically, you first substitute with an empty string everything that precedes the `T` and the `T` itself. Then, you substitute with an empty string the part starting with  `-` (there is a whitespace before the small dash).

---

Another option is to use groups of regular expressions to match particular patterns and select only one of the groups (in this case the second, `.+`)

```
import re
s.apply(lambda x: re.match("(.+T)(.+)( -.+)", x).group(2))
# 0    16:30.00
# 1    00:25.00
# dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you, using datetime library is another way to do it. I found it in one of the stackoverflow answers.

Comment: Seen, very useful link!

Comment: @S_Scouse Just added another solution if you want to check it out

Comment: Thank you, very useful. I might use it for some other string selection need.